# How to return number of distinc string repeatance separated by white Space in String?

Tags: java, regex, string

Given a StringX with characters repeated in a fashion of which it is not tied to each other, this method returns the distinct number of times such string of character is present in StringX.
E.g String y = "the green thermometer in the room" has "the" repeated in three places, THE green THErmometer in THE room, but only the first and last are distinct separated by white space. the method ignores the second occurrence of THE and returns "2"
using a bruteforce approach.

The code has a bug I can't fix since I am learning java if the first letter of the string argument is indented with a space,like  " example" instead of "example" it gives a result I cant even tell how it came about with. 
A simplified efficient approach will be much appreciated.

```
    class Test{
    public Test(){
    }

    private int numberOfDistinctOccurence(String string, String token) {
        int tokLength = token.length();
        boolean lastEndsWithSpace, previousIsSpace, nextIsSpace, isFirstSentence;
        boolean isEqual = lastEndsWithSpace = previousIsSpace = nextIsSpace = isFirstSentence = false;
        int count = 0;
        for (int shift = 0, stopCount = 0; stopCount < string.length() - token.length(); 
                                                    stopCount++, shift++, tokLength++) {
            isEqual = (string.substring(shift, tokLength).equalsIgnoreCase(token));
            lastEndsWithSpace = (string.substring(string.length()).equals(" ") || 
                                    (string.substring(string.length()).equals("")));
            if (shift == 1) {
                previousIsSpace = (string.substring(shift - 1, shift).equals(" "));
            }
            nextIsSpace = (string.substring(tokLength, tokLength + 1).equals(" "));
            isFirstSentence = (shift == 0 && string.substring(0, 0).equals("") || nextIsSpace);
            if (isEqual && isFirstSentence) {
                count++;
            } else if (isEqual && nextIsSpace || lastEndsWithSpace && previousIsSpace) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        int x = string.lastIndexOf(token.substring(token.length())); // index of last tokens char
        if (string.substring(x - token.length(), x).equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
            if (string.length() == token.length() && string.equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
            } else {
                count = (string.substring(x - token.length() - 1, x - token.length()).
                                            equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) ? count + 1 : count;
            }
        }
        return count = string.length() == token.length() && string.equalsIgnoreCase(token) ? 1 : count;

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.numberOfDistinctOccurence("The green Thermometer in the house", "he"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So you wish to only match string `the` and discard occurrence of string in other words ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use an extra array with [String#split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I guess and it's only a  **guess** that your problem could be simplified using regex if you clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: you mean that it must return `2` for `"the green thermometer in the room"`?

Comment: @FaNaJ that is what it does, but it has a bug if the first char of a string is indented with space or tab. Also, I feel a little less cumbersome approach with less code will be easy to read. but that is the best I could come up with which I feel untidy

Comment: @Nexima360: Please explain what you actually want to do. There could be a better way by using regex.

Comment: @noob exactly. match only the surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: You mean `the` only. Not `the` in thermometer ?

Comment: If you need to match `the`as a whole word, use a regex `"\\bthe\\b"`

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/p8TCzY)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hahhaha! I laughed at myself after seeing FaNaj and your solution.  Thanks will surly look into regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `\\b` to match a whole word :

```
static int numberOfDistinctOccurrence(String source, String token) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\b" + token + "\\b\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    int c = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

**EDIT** :

it also works for non `\\w` characters :

```
static int numberOfDistinctOccurrence(String source, String token) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s*\\b|\\s+)" + Pattern.quote(token) + "(\\b\\s*|\\s+|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    int c = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

for example :

```
System.out.println(numberOfDistinctOccurrence("the green thermometer in the room", "the")); // 2
System.out.println(numberOfDistinctOccurrence("the green thermometer in the+ room", "the")); // 2
System.out.println(numberOfDistinctOccurrence("the green thermometer in the+ room", "the+")); // 1
```

**EDIT (due to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)'s comment)** :

The regex should be changed to :

```
"(\\b|[^\\w])" + Pattern.quote(token) + "(\\b|[^\\w])"
```

Comment: This solution will not match a token that starts/ends with a non-word character next to punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your whitespace issue:
Add one line to the head of the method body:

```
String trimmed = string.trim();
```

and replace all occurance of *string* to *trimmed*. That's it.